# Sharepoint 2013 Performance Issue

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, performance

I am currently having issues in all of My SharePoint Environments (Testing,Production and Development ) ,All the pages are taking in between 6-8 seconds to load and for debugging i enabled developer dashboard and observed something called RobotsMetaTag Control Render to be the culprit (Its the same thing in all the environments  .I am attaching the screenshot of the developer dashboard which shows a huge spike once it come to the request

Can you please suggest me whats the reason behind this and any solution to that ,Also we have a very robust environments with separate servers for SharePoint Services and Load balanced web front end servers .

[image]
[image: SQL Response Times]

**An Update**

I tried to disable the search service and check if there is any improvement in the performance but unfortunately its the same.The only thing i observed today is even one more environment is having the same issue .Can you suggest if i am missing something

**One more Update**

I went through the ULS logs and for every page request ,i am seeing the below 2 entries in my log files .Does this have any thing to do with the performance?

> UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized.
>
> Unexpected Exception in
>   SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper::InitializeDataCacheFactory for usage
>   'DistributedViewStateCache' - Exception
>   'Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheException:

Thanks a lot for all the comments

Comment: did you see any SQL query which taking this much time under the SQL tab?

Comment: Yes its not taking much time i am adding one more Screenshot showing SQL

Comment: do you have Search engine optimization or any customization on the page? the SharePoint robots meta tag helps control webpage search engine indexing, visibility and navigation/redirection.

Comment: No i just configured the OOTB search ..this page is just an empty team site .Is there something that needs to be done on the search .Please let me know ,Thanks a lot for the quick answer ,

Comment: What is the RAM Configuration for these servers?

Comment: The Werbfront end servers are 16Gb each .We have 4 of them and 3 Application Servers each with 24 GB RAM

Comment: "UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized." is typically the search crawler I think

Comment: Check if the SP master page has the robotsmeta tag .

Comment: try commenting this "<SharePoint:RobotsMetaTag runat="server"/>"

Comment: if commenting doesnt help , try http://sureshpydi.blogspot.com/2013/10/sharepoint-seo-and-robotstxt.html . I am sure it has to something with this tag .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if you Distributed Cache service is working fine and has all the Default Cache items available.

From SP 2013 Management Console, run below commands:

```
Use-CacheCluster
Get-CacheHost
Get-Cache
```

At this stage if the console shows empty cache list, then you might have lost the cache for some reason.

To recreate them try the below:

1. Get the farm id by running

   Get-SPFarm | Select ID

Then run the below commands,  by replacing the guid from above command

```
New-Cache -CacheName DistributedLogonTokenCache_<<Farm GUID here>>

New-Cache -CacheName DistributedActivityFeedCache_<<Farm GUID here>>

New-Cache -CacheName DistributedActivityFeedLMTCache_<<Farm GUID here>>

New-Cache -CacheName DistributedBouncerCache_<<Farm GUID here>>

New-Cache -CacheName DistributedAccessCache_<<Farm GUID here>>

New-Cache -CacheName DistributedSearchCache_<<Farm GUID here>>

New-Cache -CacheName DistributedSecurityTrimmingCache_<<Farm GUID here>>

New-Cache -CacheName DistributedServerToAppServerAccessTokenCache_<<Farm GUID here>>

New-Cache -CacheName DistributedViewStateCache_<<Farm GUID here>>

New-Cache -CacheName DistributedDefaultCache_<<Farm GUID here>>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Reva your answer helped me to go in the correct direction , i did a graceful shutdown of DC and restarted the cache host again and the performance is improved

Answer (score 2):

Have you check the following:

- The recovery model for the content database (a SQL Server setting) is
  set to full by default.
- Search indexing, if it kicks in, consumes resources that you might
  need on your WFEs and SQL servers for processing the migration of
  files
- Anti-virus software, if it is scanning every document that is uploaded, or is scanning the database or BLOB store directly, can slow things down tremendously
- BLOB storage can affect performance—for better or worse.
- Database growth sizing
- Storage performance, of course, can affect the upload.
- The web front end (WFE) can be a bottleneck. Consider uploading to a dedicated web front end that is not being hit by users (though it’s typically the SQL side that’s the bottleneck)… you can target your migration using DNS or load balancer settings
- The bottleneck might be the connection between the WFE and SQL Server. Use a dedicated high-speed (Gig-E or 10Gig-E) network between WFE and SQL servers. Use teaming if NICs support it.
- The client side can also be a bottleneck, as can requests that aren’t load balanced. Consider running the migration directly on the WFE or from multiple clients, depending on your infrastructure.
- The source can be the bottleneck. Consider all of the previous issues as to where the files are coming from?  Should you perform the upload from the file server, for example? Should you move or copy the files to disks that are local to the WFE to maximize performance of the actual upload? That kind of two-step process may help you migrate during specific time windows of  your service level agreements.

source:
http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint/10-reasons-why-sharepoint-performance-can-slow

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for the checklist .I have one question ,we have always on in SQL for HA and DR will changing the recovery model will effect that ??

Answer (score -1):

Have you try to stop distributed cache.

http://blog.blksthl.com/2013/05/15/sharepoint-2013-page-loads-takes-a-very-long-time/

Comment: This is typically a last resort, and certainly not advised. OP should first make sure SQL and SharePoint servers have good enough resources in terms of memory, hdd and CPU

Comment: that is for troubleshooting to find out if the distributed cache has been implemented correctly I should state it my post. If it make any impact than it would to reconfigure the distributed cache and check if the correct username been assigned

Comment: Hi Robert ..We have 10 servers in Prod 4 for WFE 3 For Batch Processing 3 for search ..4 WFE with 16GB RAM and 3 APP with 24 GB RAM..Is there any thing else we have to check..thanks